# How do I enable HTTP Compression when using servicestack with IIS8

Tags: compression, servicestack

I had a project that built on the latest version of servicestack 4. And it seems the response will always not including content-coding:gzip whatever I tried. I've already enabled the dynamic compression on the IIS. Don't know what else to do.

Do I need to add something to my coding? I thought it will automatically use compression if supported, NO?

Really need someone to point a direction

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add a header you can always add a GZip ContentEncoding Response Header with a Response Filter, e.g:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => 
    res.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.ContentEncoding, CompressionTypes.GZip));
```

But ServiceStack only [compresses cached responses itself](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching#cache-a-response-of-a-service) i.e. when using `ToOptimizedResult()` API's or returning a responses in a `CompressedResult`, e.g:

```
public object Get(CachedOrders request)
{
    var cacheKey = "unique_key_for_this_request";
    return base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache,cacheKey,()=> 
    {
        //Delegate is executed if item doesn't exist in cache 
        //Any response DTO returned here will be cached automatically
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Very helpful. That's exactly what I want.